# How to override a focus on tab or user click (focus)

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my form validation, on submit, I am validating the form, and finding the unfilled element and focusing using this function: works fine

```
switch (tagName) {
  case 'TEXT':
      if (!actualValue) {
          $(target).next('.error').css('display', 'block');
          that.submitIt = false;
          target.select();
      } else {
          $(target).next('.error').css('display', 'none');
          that.submitIt = true;
      }
      break;
  case "SELECT-ONE":
      if (actualValue === 'Select') {
          $(target).next('.error').css('display', 'block');
          that.submitIt = false;
          target.select();
      } else {
          $(target).next('.error').css('display', 'none');
          submitIt = true
      }
      break;
  case "RADIO":
  case "CHECKBOX":
      if (actualValue && actualValue !== 'undefined') {
          $(target).siblings('.error').css('display', 'none');
          that.submitIt = true;
      } else {
          $(target).siblings('.error').css('display', 'block');
          that.submitIt = false;
          target.select();
      }
      break;
}
```

But the problem is, the function not allowing the user to move next (using tab or manually switch to next field ).

How to override the focus on tab or manual move (focus) or arrow keys?

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3gwebtrain/68kv5/25/)

Comment: Can you please also post your HTML code?

Comment: In your demo everything's works fine for me and I can jump from the current field to the next one using TAB button.

Comment: your demo doesn't have the problem you mentioned

Comment: sorry for the wrong url. check now - url updated. (http://jsfiddle.net/3gwebtrain/68kv5/25/)

Comment: The same. Everything's works as expected.

Comment: Well. Now I see the problem. Your code works fine in Firefox, but fails in Chrome.

Comment: oh...  how to overcome with this?

Comment: When the field is empty your validation keeps on the same field as long as you write a value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem lies in the `target.select()` lines. Every time you validate your input field and the validation fails (e.g. when you try to leave the field) it will re-select that same field.

EDIT: Since you validate on focusout and then re-select I really don't see any other way around it than removing the `target.select()`. You can't have your cake and eat, as they say. The alternative is to only validate on submit.

The JQuery validation plugin, for instance, will mark a field as invalid on change and focusout, but won't select it. Probably because of this problem.

Comment: I am looking for overcome from this..!? looking some good approach

Comment: Is there a way to kill a focus on setInterval?